# Way to construct Innosetup setup script from Executable

Tags: inno-setup

I had put little bit effort to create an Inno installer.It had around 2 files.I just missed backuping 1 file.So is there a way to contruct the inno setup script from the compiled installer.

Comment: Yes, but you can lose e.g. scripting code section. There are tools like e.g. [`innoextract`](http://constexpr.org/innoextract/), or [`innounp`](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/) which can decompile the setup binary, build a script and/or extract contained files.

Comment: @TLama Thanks.Tried inno extract its just a tool to decompress the bundle.There is no mention of getting the code.What im looking for is a way to get the code used to create the installer.Like i referenced a piece of code from another.I have only 1 file missing the second.

Comment: Then try the other one. I'm sure that innounp could build a script (haven't ever tried innoextract).

Comment: @TLama Tried innounp with the -x command and -m option.It generated an unreadable CompiledCode.bin file.Well seems like i need to rewrite the code.

Comment: Probably yes. I'm not aware of any other *working* decompiler.

Comment: @TLama I needed to disassemble the bin file using ifps3_disasm.rar But it created assembly code... will go with writing new code. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open install.exe file with innosetup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697709/is-it-possible-to-open-install-exe-file-with-innosetup)