# Is it possible to extract an installer built with Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have one install.exe file. Is it possible to open .exe file with Inno Setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this program Inno Setup Unpacker

http://innounp.sourceforge.net/

It is not official, but it may work with your .exe file and may restore something from it.

Files other than .iss you can get just by installing your exe file.